# Adding a new record to an Access database via vb.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

Do i need to have a new ID generate within vb if I have it set to AutoID in the table itself?
I currently have

```
Protected Sub deleteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles deleteButton.Click
    Dim deleteSQL As String
    deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM Authors WHERE au_id=@au_id"
    Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(deleteSQL, myConnection)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@au_id", authorDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value)
    Dim successBoolean As Boolean = True
    Dim index As Integer = authorDropDownList.SelectedIndex
    Try
        myConnection.Open()
        successBoolean = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
        'authorLabel.Text = "Record Deleted"
        'authorLabel.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        successBoolean = False
        authorLabel.Text = "Error deleting author. " & ex.Message
        authorLabel.Visible = True
    Finally
        myConnection.Close()
    End Try
    If successBoolean Then
        FillAutherList(index)
        authorDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e)
        authorLabel.Text = "Record Deleted"
        authorLabel.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub


Dim insertSQL As New StringBuilder
    Dim currentDate As String
    currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString
    insertSQL.Append("INSERT INTO Story_Table (Author,Content,Submission_Date)") 'Inserts new story
    insertSQL.Append(" VALUES (@Author,@Content,@Submission_Date)")             'Sets the story values
    Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSQL.ToString, myConnection)
    With myCommand.Parameters                        'Do this next
        .AddWithValue("@Author", authorTextBox.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@Content", storyTextBox.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@Submission_Date", currentDate)
    End With
    Dim successBoolean As Boolean = True
    Try
        myConnection.Open()
        successBoolean = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
        resultLabel.Text = "Thanks for the Story! Look for it on the homepage."
        resultLabel.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        successBoolean = False
        resultLabel.Text = "Error inserting story. " & ex.Message
        resultLabel.Visible = True
        storyLabel.Text = storyTextBox.Text
        storyLabel.Visible = True
    Finally
        myConnection.Close()
    End Try`
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue with the large amount of code you posted with no explanation?

Comment: I am trying to insert a new record into an Access Table that will be displayed on another page. I am having trouble figuring out how the autoID works in vb. Do I need to have a new ID be generated or will it do it for me?

Comment: I thought my question was clear, but I'll try again. You posted a large amount of code in your question. Are you having problems with it? (Is it working, or not? Do you get errors? What happens when you run it?) You posted a generic "Do I need to have a new ID generate...?" question with a few dozen lines of code with no indication of what the code was included for - I'm trying to find out why you felt it was necessary to post it all with no explanation. Your question was only about inserting data, so the only part that seems pertinent is the `insertSQL` portion, but that's not even clear.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. It is giving me an error saying that "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\dclifford14\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\FinalProject\App_Data\Final_Project_Database.accdb failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share." How would I go about creating a new entry to the table?

Comment: Read the error message. It has nothing to do with adding an entry to the table. The error clearly says "A database with the same name exists, **or the specified file cannot be opened**, or it is located on a UNC share". This is not a problem inserting data - it's a problem opening the database. It's very important you actually read the words the error message contains, instead of just assuming you know what's causing the problem. (And the information about getting an error and the error message should be added to your question, not placed in comments, so people can see it.)